# Get data as response from php script on server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm sending some data(options) via POST with javascript to a php script that's on my server, which does a mysql query and should return data back to the current page.

This is the jquery code I'm using -

```
$.post( "contact.php",  {min_age:"25"})
  .done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Now I've got the required data extracted from mysql and encoded it to json, and stored it in a variable in my php script in server. How do I post it back to the current page?

Comment: The response is a JSON data? You want to write the content on your page?

Comment: So what is your question here? The `data` variable in the jQuery post would be what is returned from your web server

Comment: All you need to do is parse `data`.

Comment: To place it back into your page you can use `$("#response").html(data);` provided you have a container named `response` and you have the `data` as suggested above. This would be in your success function.

Comment: try reading the jQuery Docs

Comment: @Rasclatt that won't work well with JSON as mentioned by OP

Comment: @charlietfl yeah, true, I missed the whole jSON comment there. Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to 'send the data' from php, you need to echo it, after setting the correct header:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: You may also set, `}, 'json');` as the last argument to the `$.post()` method to have your `data` interpreted as JSON.